# ArrayList doesn't return any values

Tags: arraylist

I'm returning an ArrayList which doesn't return the values that have been added to it.

```
package pack1;
public class file{
private ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

public void method(){
  arraylist.add("value");
  arraylist.add("value2");
  arraylist.add("value3");
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){ //returns the arraylist
  return arraylist;
}

}
```

the above is the values that I added to the array and I want to retrieve the data in another class and its also located in another source folder.

```
package pack2;

public class retrieve{
   public file obj; //object from file
  
   public void method(){
       obj = new file();
       ArrayList<String> arraylist2 = obj.getArrayList;

       for(String arr : arraylist2){
          System.out.println(arr);
       }
   }
}
```

and in the retrieve class I'm trying to get the data, but it doesn't show up and the size of the array is 0 when using the size() which means that it hasn't returned any elements at all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You haven't called method() from class 'file'. So arraylist is empty by default.

Comment: that unfortunately doesn't work, also whenever i'm making getters for variables it also doesn't return the value, maybe its because im using EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()); method